# jQuery serialize and unserialize

Tags: jquery

I want to serialize and un-serialize a form with jQuery.

How can I get all attributes of all elements in a serialized way?

Comment: **2020:** see my answer below for `unserialize()` : https://stackoverflow.com/a/65963742/1835470

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery has a `serialize` function.

```
$("#form").serialize(); // Returns serialized string
```

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: what about unserialize?

Comment: @PabloPazos current way - see my answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/65963742/1835470 the **old** way is to manually parse it by & and = and decodeURIComponent both keys and values, **don't do that yourself unless you absolutely have to :)**

Answer (score 17):

[.serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) will map your input controls that have a **name** attribute defined into a standard query string:

```
foo=bar&bar=foo&and=soon
```

That kind of string is easy accesible in almost every "backend" programming language.

If you need to serialize object information, use `JSON`.

```
var obj = {
    foo:  'bar',
    more: 'etc
};
```

serialize this with `window.JSON.stringify(obj);`. To unserialize such a JSON string, use `window.JSON.parse(str);`, which returns a javascript object.

Many languages support this principle.

Comment: hi there, why do jquery use name attribute to serialize a form (instead of using id attribute?)

Comment: @frabiacca because that is how HTTP POST and HTTP GET work. They use the name for the variable name, and value for the variable value. Name value pairs. Name=value & varnam=varval & custvar=custval... etc..

Answer (score 7):

## 2020 solution

### `serialize()`

Is included in jQuery itself for this very purpose https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

`$('#someKind .ofASelectorForYour form').serialize();` (returns serialized string)

### `unserialize()`

Is not included in jQuery, but, the documentation says

> The .serialize() method creates a text string in standard URL-encoded notation.

...so, in 2020, we can leverage the `URLSearchParams` interface:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams

https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-urlsearchparams

```
function unserialize(serializedData) {
    let urlParams = new URLSearchParams(serializedData); // get interface / iterator
    let unserializedData = {}; // prepare result object
    for (let [key, value] of urlParams) { // get pair > extract it to key/value
        unserializedData[key] = value;
    }

    return unserializedData;
}
```

(returns object of unserialized key => value pairs)

A one-liner for one-time usage extractor (your data in `sData`, result in `unsData`):

```
let prms = new URLSearchParams(sData); let unsData = {}; for (let [k, v] of prms) unsData[k] = v;
```

BTW: as MDN docs say,

> following two lines are equivalent:
>
> `for (const [key, value] of mySearchParams) {}`
>
> `for (const [key, value] of mySearchParams.entries()) {}`

Comment: It was missing the case for array values like a multioption select

`...
    for ([key, value] of urlParams) {
        if (key.endsWith('[]')) {
          const arrayKeyName = key.slice(0, -2);
          if (!unserializedData[arrayKeyName]) {
             unserializedData[arrayKeyName] = [];
          }
          unserializedData[arrayKeyName].push(value);
        } else {
          unserializedData[key] = value;
        }
    }

    return unserializedData;
}`

Answer (score 2):

If you want unserialize you must create a function like this;

```
function unserialize(data) {
    data = data.split('&');
    var response = {};
    for (var k in data){
        var newData = data[k].split('=');
        response[newData[0]] = newData[1];
    }
    return response;
}
```

this function inverse serialize() and return a json data.

Comment: Although this is a good starting point, it is **NOT** a complete inverse of `serialize()` since it does not care about URI component encoding, which will ultimately fail for nested keys, special characters, diacritics, etc... Try to leverage the new way - https://stackoverflow.com/a/65963742/1835470 :)

Answer (score 1):

All elements in the form will be sent along if using the `$('form').serialize();`