# How to pass selected value by jQuery

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I want to pass selected value on invoice.php file using jQuery. After sending value on invoice.php file. I want to show invoice.php file echo result on index.php page selected input box. Like an example:  If anyone select Item then rate show on rate input box. Here is my code and image[image]

index.php file code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Invoice</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".item").change(function(){
        calculate();
    });
});

function calculate() {

var item = [];
    $(".item").each(function() {
            var num=(this.value);
            item.push(num);
    });


    $('input[name=rate]').each(function(i){
        $.get(
            '/invoice_final_2.php',
            {'product':item[i]},
            function(data) {
                $(this).html(data);
            });
    });
}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
</script>
<style type="text/css">
table
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: none;
    width: 300px;
}


td
{
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
#first
{
    border-left: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method='post' name='form1' action='welcome.php'>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td id="first">Item</td>
                <td>Rate</td>
            </tr>
            <?php
            $num=4;
            for ($i=0; $i<$num; $i++)
            {
                echo "
                 <tr>
                 <td id='first'>
                 <select class='item' name='item'>
                 <option>Select one</option>
                 <option>Deluxe Plan</option>
                 <option>Premium Plan</option>
                 <option>Standard Plan</option>
                 <option>Economy Plan</option>
                 </select>
                </td>
                <td><input class='rate' type='text' name='rate'/></td>
               </tr>";
            }
            ?>
     </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

invoice.php file code:

```
<?php
include "dbconnect.php";

$product=$_GET['product'];

$query="select * from item where item_name='$product'";
$result=mysql_query or die (mysql_error());
$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$rate=$row['rate'];

echo "$rate";

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, but you don't need to use `each` and send values one by one using indexes, you can send the array *once*.

```
function calculate() {
    var items = $(".item").map(function() {
          return this.value;
    }).get();

    $.get('/invoice_final_2.php',
        {'product': items },
        function(data) {
           //
        }
    );
}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: If I use array then How to show this array on index.php file selected input box. can you explain please.

Comment: @user1493448 Then you should iterate through the array and read the values, I would serialize the results, this way you can handle the data easier.

Comment: can you give me serialize example code. Because I am new in jquery. can you give me code please.

Comment: @user1493448 There are many related questions on stackoverflow see this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100297/jquery-serialize-and-unserialize